# If VTiger is in PHP, Which CRM is for Rails?

Tags: php, .net, ruby-on-rails, crm, vtiger

I come from a .NET background and just learned Ruby On Rails. My company uses VTiger for Customer Relationship Management. I have no idea about PHP. I am a rails fan, instead of me learning PHP to work on VTiger, I am looking for a solution in Rails. I found [Fat Free CRM](http://www.fatfreecrm.com/). Is it good? Also, Are their any better ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FatFreeCRM is very good. The code is very clean and out of the box it will give you most of what you need.

I have 0.10.1 running on a Heroku instance. FatFreeCRM exposes a restful API which you can connect to with ActiveResource.

It also has a plugin framework which allows you to extend it as you wish.

Finally, the dropbox feature is great, I can forward email to a special gmail account I've set up and my FatFreeCRM install will pick them up and attach them to the relevant contacts.